# Refresh a WebView in a ViewController from another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, webview, protocols, popover

Hi I am relatively still a newbie to objective C - but in the deep end with what I need to accomplish.

I am trying to refresh a webview in a ViewController when I click on its popover table cell, whose tableView is generated from another ViewController.

I have read everywhere I need to use @protocol. So I have implemented it as follows:

In the .h file where the popover is generated I inserted:

```
@protocol updateViewController

-(void)updateView;

@end
```

I then added a property and synthesised:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id <updateViewController> viewControllerDelegate;
```

in the .h file of the tableview (which gets used as the popover) I inserted:

```
#import "NDSClassViewController.h"

@interface NDSClassMainMenuViewController : UITableViewController <updateViewController>
```

Now I want to access the method from the .m file of the viewController where the web view is located to refresh it.

I cant use the [updateViewController *methodname*] as directed, so I must be misunderstanding something.

I'd appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

give your `yourtableview.viewControllerDelegate=self` in viewdidload of the viewcontroller where your webview is created 
So viewControllerDelegate knows that it have to call the method that is implmented in the viewcontroller with webview

Comment: Thanks for answering. I inserted that code. I get a yellow warning, it says: assigning to _strong ... from incompatible type ... const_strong.

Comment: you have to right yourtableview.viewControllerDelegate=self. sorry i miss that.